# Git adds '~HEAD_0' to the end of file

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm new to Git and I'm having the following problem: after rebase, Git added to pull request 2 files appending `~HEAD_0` to the end of filenames.

So it looks like this: `InfoViewController.m~HEAD_0`

1. It does not create a new file; this thing with a `~HEAD_0` suffix exist only in the commit message on Bitbucket.
2. The file with `~HEAD_0` contains a snapshot of last state of the parent branch.

What's going on, and should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the files which are in you current branch and not in the upstream will be stored in temporary area. as git-rebase documentation says.

> All changes made by commits in the current branch but that are not in
>  are saved to a temporary area. This is the same set of
> commits that would be shown by git log ..HEAD; or by git log
> 'fork_point'..HEAD, if --fork-point is active (see the description on
> --fork-point below); or by git log HEAD, if the --root option is specified.
>
> The current branch is reset to , or  if the --onto
> option was supplied. This has the exact same effect as git reset
> --hard  (or ). ORIG_HEAD is set to point at the tip of the branch before the reset.
>
> The commits that were previously saved into the temporary area are
> then reapplied to the current branch, one by one, in order. Note that
> any commits in HEAD which introduce the same textual changes as a
> commit in HEAD.. are omitted (i.e., a patch already accepted
> upstream with a different commit message or timestamp will be
> skipped).

so the files which are not in the upstream, will eventually appends *..HEAD*

Comment: Your quote (where is it from?) says nothing about a `~HEAD_0` suffix.